# I need a help in finding the time and space complexity for the below code?

Tags: python

Can anyone help in finding the time and space complexity for the below code?

```
    text=input()
    a=text.split()
    c=0
    b=[]
    d=[]
    for i in a:
       if not i in b:
          b.append(i)

    for i in b:
       c=0
       for j in a:
          if i == j:
             c+=1
        d.append(c)

   print(b, end="\t")
   print('\n')
   print(d, end='\t')
```

Comment: Perhaps start by explaining what the code is doing

Comment: Seems to me this is `O(len(a)*len(b))`

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Answer (score 0):

Let's count the number of operations of this loop

```
for i in a:
    if not i in b:
        b.append(i)
```

For the kth element of `a`, you have to perform at most `k-1` operations to find out if `i` is in `b` or not. That means that in the worst case, the number of operation is O`(len(a)^2)`.

Indeed, the maximal number of operations is the sum of k-1 for k from 1 to `len(a)` which is equal to `len(a) * (len(a) -1) /2`.

Let's now look at the loop

```
    for i in b:
       c=0
       for j in a:
          if i == j:
             c+=1
        d.append(c)
```

In the worst case, `len(a)` is equal to `len(b)`, and here again, the complexity is O`(len(a)^2)`.

So the total complexity is O`(len(a)^2)`.